# Android how to call java function from JNI with ArrayList as out parameter

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a java function like

```
public void OnResult(int i, ArrayList<String> a_strList);
```

I want to call this function from JNI C++.

I have added code which is the following throwing exception :

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError..
>
> mID=a_pEnv->GetMethodID(javaclass, "OnResult", "(ILjava/lang/ArrayList;)V");

please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but may help others: it should be "(ILjava/**util**/ArrayList;)V".

You can use the "javap -s myclass.class" command to get the right descriptor for your methods automatically (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javap.html) for params).